# How to use if else conditions with overloaded constructor in java

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor-overloading

Our prof give us an activity to create a overloaded constructor that stores blood type.  I've already Created two (2) classes named BloodData (no class modifier) and RunBloodData (public). My problem is I don't how to apply the if else statements to this 2 objects in the main method, if the user does not input anything Hence, the values stored in the default constructor are displayed.

```
public class RunBloodData {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter blood type of patient: ");
String input1 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the Rhesus Factor (+ or -): ");
String input2 = input.nextLine();

//How to use conditions in this 2 objects with agruments and w/out arguments?

BloodData bd = new BloodData(input1,input2);
bd.display();
System.out.println(" is added to the blood bank.");   

// if the user did not input values, the values stored in the default constructor should display this.
BloodData bd = new BloodData();
bd.display();
System.out.println(" is added to the blood bank.");


//constructor
class BloodData {
static String bloodType;
static String rhFactor;

public BloodData() {
bloodType = "O";
rhFactor = "+";   
}
public BloodData(String bt, String rh) {
bloodType = bt;
rhFactor = rh;
}static
public void display(){
System.out.print(bloodType+rhFactor);
  
 }
}
// this is the output of it
Enter blood type of patient: B
Enter the Rhesus Factor (+ or -): -
B- is added to the blood bank.
O+ is added to the blood bank.//this should not be displayed since the user input values. How to fix it?
```

This is a part of the instruction in the activity. --In the main method, add statements to ask the user to input the blood type and the Rhesus factor (+ or -). Instantiate a BloodData object name with arguments based on the user input. For example, BloodData bd new BloodData(inputl, input2); where input1 and input2 are String variables that stored what the user entered. If the user does not input anything, instantiate a BloodData object without an argument. Print the confirmation message by invoking the display method through the object you created For example, bd. disp1ay;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to check if the inputs are equal to an empty string ("") using .equals(). For example:

```
if (input1.equals("") && input2.equals(""))
    BloodData bd = new BloodData();
    // ...
else
    BloodData bd = new BloodData(input1,input2);
    // ...
```

However, this won't account for if your user enters nothing for one input, but something for the other. I'd add a condition to account for that, such as asking the user for input again.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will take the input from the user and checks if both the inputs are not empty. If one of them is empty then it will invoke constructor without parameter and prints message accordingly.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class RunBloodData {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter blood type of patient: ");
  String input1 = input.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Enter the Rhesus Factor (+ or -): ");
  String input2 = input.nextLine();
  BloodData bd = null;
  if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(input1) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(input2)) {
    bd = new BloodData(input1,input2);
  } else {
    bd = new BloodData();
  }
  bd.display();
  System.out.println(" is added to the blood bank.");  

  class BloodData {
    static String bloodType;
    static String rhFactor;

    public BloodData() {
      bloodType = "O";
      rhFactor = "+";   
    }

    public BloodData(String bt, String rh) {
      bloodType = bt;
      rhFactor = rh;
    }
    public void display(){
      System.out.print(bloodType+rhFactor);
    }
}
```